# How to use semantic-ui in react with webpack?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, commonjs, semantic-ui

I would like to use CommonJS to include semantic-ui in my react jsx file. I installed semantic-ui with bower, and webpack is correctly configured to include the bower_components directory.

However, when I use
`require('semantic-ui/dist/semantic-ui.js')` in the jsx file, the console always throw an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", even when I put a statement `var jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.js')` before that.

Another related thing is that in order for semantic-ui to work, semantic.css should also be included. I am also wondering how to include semantic.css in jsx file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the CSS you're going to want to load that in your index/whatever.html file before sourcing your JS.

Try the following before you require semantic-ui:

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.js');
window.jQuery = $; // Assure it's available globally.
var s = require('semantic-ui/dist/semantic-ui.js');
```

Not 100% sure this will work but it's worth a try.

Things can get tricky with CommonJS modules. Also, might be worth looking into React+Browserify. Makes it super simple to import NPM modules using `require`.

Answer (score 12):

try the [provide-plugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) like so:

```
  plugins: [
    new ProvidePlugin({
      'jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
```

Comment: the accepted answer works, but this is the correct, best practices answer