# Load Semantic UI jQuery Plugins with Webpack 2 and React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui, webpack-dev-server

Struggling to get Semantic UI jQuery components to behave using Webpack 2 and React. I am able to import all the required files, but I'm getting a run-time exception when attempting to call Semantic UI jQuery functions. I've seen these SO articles:

- [Loading jQuery plugins with webpack 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120485/loading-jquery-plugins-with-webpack-2)
- [Webpack 2 issues with Semantic UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321529/webpack-2-issues-with-semantic-ui)
- [How to use semantic-ui in react with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180056/how-to-use-semantic-ui-in-react-with-webpack)

all of which are all related to consuming jQuery in the Webpack context, but not about run-time exceptions.

I did a simple trial with HMR

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

import { Accordion, Button, Form, Icon, Header, Container, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import css from 'semantic_source/semantic.less';
import '../../semantic/dist/semantic'

import $ from 'jQuery';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Container text>
                <Segment padded raised container>
                {/* ... */}
```

**Note:** Full file can be seen [here](https://github.com/atomicpages/semantic-ui-webpack2-boilerplate/blob/react/app/components/App.jsx).

I render my app as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'; // AppContainer is a necessary wrapper component for HMR

import App from './components/App.jsx';

const render = Component => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Component/>
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
};

render(App);

// Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./components/App.jsx', () => {
        render(App)
    });
}
```

despite having the required dependencies, I'm getting this run-time error:

```
App.jsx?fbf8:14 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_jQuery___default(...)(...).accordion is not a function
    at App.componentDidMount (eval at ./app/components/App.jsx (bundle.js:721), <anonymous>:80:77)
    at App.proxiedComponentDidMount (eval at ./node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/modules/createPrototypeProxy.js (bundle.js:10019), <anonymous>:61:40)
```

I opened my dev tools console and did a simple test to ensure everything was loaded via webpack:

```
 $('.ui.accordion').accordion(); // it works
```

- Where is the right place to call this jQuery initialization?
- Can this be done directly in the `.jsx` file?
- Is `componentDidMount` the correct lifecycle callback to use?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I'm having exactly the same issue in a Vue.js context.  I cannot get it to take the Semantic JS.  I get a stalled build too, no errors.  Tried it 5+ ways.